# Combining 2 queries into one

Tags: php, mysqli, query-optimization

I have these 2 queries:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(points) as userpoints FROM ".$prefix."_publicpoints
                        WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ? AND fk_player_id = ?";

// Getting the users points into a variable to use in the next query
$userPoints;

$getuserplacement = "SELECT fk_player_id FROM ".$prefix."_publicpoints
                            WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ?
                                GROUP BY fk_player_id
                            HAVING SUM(points) > $userPoints";

// After this I count the rows I get and put that into a variable and thats the users Rank
$userRank = $stmt->num_rows + 1;
```

This gives me these numbers: Points:-178 Placement: 1891

I have then tried the example by Ivan:

```
    $sql= "SELECT fk_player_id FROM ".$prefix."_publicpoints
                        WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ?
                            GROUP BY fk_player_id
                        HAVING SUM(points) > (
             SELECT SUM(points) as userpoints FROM ".$prefix."_publicpoints
                        WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ? AND fk_player_id = ?
   )";

if($stmt->prepare($sql)){
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssi',$yearFrom,$yearTo,$yearFrom,$yearTo,$playerid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $userMrank = $stmt->num_rows;
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }
    $stmt->bind_result($userPoints);
    $stmt->fetch();
}
```

This gives me these numbers: Points:3 Placement: 0

Is it possible to combine these 2 queries into one?

Hoping for help :-)

Comment: I can't understand your question after your edit, which are the 2 queries?

Comment: Sorry, Edited my post again :-/

Comment: Why do you want to combine them?

Comment: To optimize and only have one query to the same table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you, but, do you want this?

```
$sql= "SELECT fk_player_id FROM ".$prefix."_publicpoints
                            WHERE date BETWEEN '$year-01-01' AND '$year-12-31'
                                GROUP BY fk_player_id
                            HAVING SUM(points) > (
                 SELECT SUM(points) as userpoints FROM ".$prefix."_publicpoints
                            WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ? AND fk_player_id = ?
       )";
```

Comment: Badly explained by me. Edited my post with the full query that you posted. It doesn't give me the right result. It gives me only 3 points when infact it should give -174 and a placement 0. Hope the edited post helps :-/